# Proof for a property of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

In the below image, $H$ is orthocenter of the $\triangle ABC$ and I need to show that quadrilateral
$ACDF$ is cyclic.

[image]

I am able to conclude that $\angle 1 =\angle 2 =90^{\circ}$  suggesting that $AC$ can be diameter of such a circle. So If I say that since line $AC$ subtends right angle at points $F$ and $D$ therefore it can be diameter of circle passing through points $A,C,D,F$. Hence these points can be concyclic if $AC$ is taken as diameter of such a circle. This question was asked to me in a class test and I wrote above proof but got a zero for it.

Can I proof this in some other better way?

Comment: Your approach, which leverages [Thales' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem), is the one I would've used. I cannot speak to why you didn't receive credit. Perhaps you were expected to use specific results covered in your class; in that case, we cannot hope to formulate an acceptable proof without knowing which results those are.

Comment: Even if you keep aside Thale's Theorem and that $AC$ is diameter, since $\angle AFC = \angle ADC$, by inscribed angles, $A, F, D$ and $C$ are con-cyclic. as @Blue said, it could be that you were supposed to prove it in a certain way based on what was covered in the class.

Comment: @Blue Keeping my class aside, is my proof correct or I can get some other proof

Comment: @MathLover are you using converse of inscribed angle theorem

Comment: @Blue I have one doubt. For AFC and ADC how can we ensure that there circumcircle is same

Comment: @LalitTolani: *"is my proof correct[?]"* I should hope so, since I said that it's the approach I would've used. :)  ... *"For AFC and ADC how can we ensure that [their] circumcircle is same[?]"* The circles have the same diameter, so they must be the same.

Comment: thankyou @Blue sir for helping me

Comment: @LalitTolani "*can be concyclic if $\color{red}{AB}$ is taken as diameter*" — Just as general advice, be careful with the typos in written tests.

Comment: To your earlier question to me, yes it comes from inscribed angle theorem. If the segment joining two points A and B subtends equal angles at two other points C and D on the same side of AB, then the four points are concyclic.

Comment: @dxiv I fixed it

Comment: @MathLover Yes I understood now but I'm not able to prove it

Comment: @LalitTolani https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Circles/The-converse-theorem-on-inscribed-angles.lesson